# Hide and show modal on same button click in Ionic1

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want hide and show a div based on same button click

**click part**

```
<a class = "tab-item" ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails">
   <i class = "icon  ion-paperclip"></i>
     Attach
</a>
```

**Edit**

I have removed modal and used only `ng-click` and tried,But here am getting true/false for each click.But my `<div>` is not visible.

```
{{showDetails}}
<div class ="bar bar-footer" ng-show="showDetails" >
<div class = "tabs tabs-icon-bottom tabs-striped tabs-color-gray hide-on-keyboard-open"  style="background-color: white;" >
 <a class = "tab-item" ng-click="myCam()">
   <i class = "icon  ion-camera"></i>
     Camera
 </a>

<a class = "tab-item" ng-click="pdfUpload()">
   <i class = "icon ion-upload"></i>
     Pdf
</a>
```

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: I've only worked with Ionic 2+ so this is tricky.

On the face of it. Is the div wrapping all the content you want to hide? I use the same approach in Ionic 2 to hide without issues ie $scope.show1 = !$scope.show1;

Comment: yes the entire `<div>`

Comment: did you make the plunker?

Answer (score 2):

`ng-click="show = ! show"` will be what you need to attach to your click event or icon.  `ng-show="show"` is what gets show and hidden on the DOM.

```
  <a class = "tab-item" ng-click="show = ! show">
   <i class = "icon  ion-paperclip"></i>
     Attach
  </a>

<div class ="bar bar-footer" ng-show="show">
 <div class = "tabs tabs-icon-bottom tabs-striped tabs-color-gray hide-on-keyboard-open" style="background-color: white;" >
<a class = "tab-item" ng-click="myCam()">
   <i class = "icon  ion-camera"></i>
     Camera
</a>

<a class = "tab-item" ng-click="pdfUpload()">
   <i class = "icon ion-upload"></i>
     Pdf
</a>
```

I hope this answer was sufficient for you. Here is a fiddle [Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/17514/)

Comment: ya i will check

Comment: Seems like it does the job nicely.

Comment: ya tht is working , But in my case its not. `{{showDetails}}
` am getting true n false for each click

Comment: But `<div>` is not showing on click donno whts wrong with it, I am just trying only so much to view `<div class ="bar bar-footer" ng-show="showDetails" >
<h1>hello</h1></div>`

Comment: @Hema can you try and make a js fiddle or place your full code? You should be able to complete the `ng-show` and `ng-hide` quite easily. I'd gladly help you if you show me your code.

Comment: @ZombieChowder i have added full code,using modal can you please check

Comment: @Hema you can show and hide the modal without using any kind of `JavaScript`. They have it pre build in `Bootstrap`, have your tried that?

Comment: No i have not used bootstrap. This is ionic app

Comment: @ZombieChowder here my css class are the issue. If i remove them it ll work fine. Can you help to fix tht

Comment: @Hema I just added a fiddle to my answer. Even if your `css` code is the issue, I can't help you without you showing me your code! So please paste your full code so I can help you solve the issue finally.

I also suggest you loot at my fiddle and see how I achieved the `ng-show` and `ng-hide` .

Answer (score 1):

Link For the Updated fiddle

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msd117/73d0wu29/3/)

Controller code

```
var SampleApp;
(function (SampleApp) {

var app = angular.module('sampleApp', ['ionic']);    
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {



    $scope.toggleStretchedMode = function() {

    $scope.showDetails= !$scope.showDetails;



  }

});

})(SampleApp || (SampleApp = {}));
```

Html Code

```
<div>       
    <div ng-app="sampleApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
         <ion-content style="display:block">
         <div class="row" ng-if="showDetails"  style="padding-left: 205px;padding-top: 128px;">
        <div class="col col-33" style="text-align:center;">
          <ul class="row" >
            <li class="col" style=" display:inline;padding: 10px 15px;">
            <a class = "tab-item" ng-click="myCam()">
            <i class = "icon  ion-camera"></i>
             Camera
            </a></li>
             <li class="col" style=" display:inline;padding: 10px 15px;" >
            <a class = "tab-item" ng-click="myCam()">
            <i class = "icon  ion-camera"></i>
             Gallery
            </a></li>
            <li class="col" style=" display:inline;padding: 10px 15px;">
            <a class = "tab-item" ng-click="pdfUpload()">
            <i class = "icon ion-upload"></i>
              Pdf
    </a></li>


          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

        </ion-content>

        <div class ="bar bar-footer">
  <div class = "tabs tabs-icon-bottom tabs-striped tabs-color-gray hide-on-keyboard-open" style="background-color: #11c1f3;">
    <a class = "tab-item" ui-sref="app.homeApp">
       <i class = "icon ion-home"></i>
     Home
    </a>

    <a class = "tab-item" ng-click="myCam()">
       <i class = "icon  ion-camera"></i>
         Camera
    </a>

    <a class = "tab-item" ng-click="toggleStretchedMode()">
       <i class = "icon  ion-paperclip"></i>
         Attach
    </a>

   </div>
</div>

    </div>     
</div>
```

Hope It helps

Comment: This will let only `show`,On next click its not hiding

Comment: @Hema  you have edited the code now.... can you please make a plunker here https://plnkr.co/

Comment: yes i have removed `$event` and tried. Am getting view but its not closing

Comment: your code is confusing ...after your edits, you are now trying to show a modal also now? so are you showing a modal or showing the div? can you please show full code or make fiddle or plunker ... that way I could understand the problem

Comment: I have tried in both ways. Just showing the <div> or showing it inside the modal.Both ways am struck. I ll post code here 2min

Comment: I would suggest remove the modal and just use div and use the controller code which I have shown in my answer,... I have updated the answer

Comment: Yes,But my view is not updating.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rojaHema/nhwyowcv/4/  my fiddel link.. Can you please check with tht

Comment: @Hema Updated the Answer and added the fiddle