# Getting pop up options like whatsApp when we click on attachment icon

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have `<div>` which should be opened on button click and closed again on same button click.

Someone marked it as duplicate,I know theme is same but the way of solving that question os different.I need in two different ways.

Here is my fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/rojaHema/nhwyowcv/4/

**As an example i need like whatsApp, how we get pop up options when clicked on attachments**

**Button**

```
<a class = "tab-item" ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails">
    <i class = "icon  ion-paperclip"></i>
    Attach
</a>
```

**Div**

```
<div class ="bar bar-footer" ng-if="showDetails" >
     <div class = "tabs tabs-icon-bottom tabs-striped tabs-color-gray hide-on-keyboard-open"  style="background-color: white;" >
          <a class = "tab-item" ng-click="myCam()">
          <i class = "icon  ion-camera"></i>camera</a>

          <a class = "tab-item" ng-click="pdfUpload()">
              <i class = "icon ion-upload"></i>
              Pdf
          </a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try calling a function instead on ng-click and set the $scope.showDetails true or false depending on the previous value

Comment: use data-target and data-toggle. It helps to achieve what you are expection. Adding my answer check it.

Comment: I have tried tht also @MaheshJadhav same issue

Comment: Yes please add your ans @KishorVelayutham

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide and show modal on same button click in Ionic1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48380735/hide-and-show-modal-on-same-button-click-in-ionic1)

Answer (score 1):

Link For the Updated fiddle

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msd117/73d0wu29/3/)

Controller code

```
var SampleApp;
(function (SampleApp) {

var app = angular.module('sampleApp', ['ionic']);    
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {



    $scope.toggleStretchedMode = function() {

    $scope.showDetails= !$scope.showDetails;



  }

});

})(SampleApp || (SampleApp = {}));
```

Html Code

```
<div>       
    <div ng-app="sampleApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
         <ion-content style="display:block">
         <div class="row" ng-if="showDetails"  style="padding-left: 205px;padding-top: 128px;">
        <div class="col col-33" style="text-align:center;">
          <ul class="row" >
            <li class="col" style=" display:inline;padding: 10px 15px;">
            <a class = "tab-item" ng-click="myCam()">
            <i class = "icon  ion-camera"></i>
             Camera
            </a></li>
             <li class="col" style=" display:inline;padding: 10px 15px;" >
            <a class = "tab-item" ng-click="myCam()">
            <i class = "icon  ion-camera"></i>
             Gallery
            </a></li>
            <li class="col" style=" display:inline;padding: 10px 15px;">
            <a class = "tab-item" ng-click="pdfUpload()">
            <i class = "icon ion-upload"></i>
              Pdf
    </a></li>


          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

        </ion-content>

        <div class ="bar bar-footer">
  <div class = "tabs tabs-icon-bottom tabs-striped tabs-color-gray hide-on-keyboard-open" style="background-color: #11c1f3;">
    <a class = "tab-item" ui-sref="app.homeApp">
       <i class = "icon ion-home"></i>
     Home
    </a>

    <a class = "tab-item" ng-click="myCam()">
       <i class = "icon  ion-camera"></i>
         Camera
    </a>

    <a class = "tab-item" ng-click="toggleStretchedMode()">
       <i class = "icon  ion-paperclip"></i>
         Attach
    </a>

   </div>
</div>

    </div>     
</div>
```

Hope It helps

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

Everything was perfect in your fiddle code, I have just added ng-app and ng-controller. And then it worked.

```js
var SampleApp;
(function (SampleApp) {

    var app = angular.module('sampleApp', ['ionic']);    
    
    app.controller('MainCtrl', function (
        $scope, 
        $ionicScrollDelegate,
        $location
        ) {
               
       
    });

})(SampleApp || (SampleApp = {}));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.9/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.9/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="sampleApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   
    <ion-view hide-back-button="true">

        <ion-content scroll="false" style="top:0px;margin-top: 45px;">          
            <div class="row" ng-show="showDetails">
                <div class="col col-33" style="text-align:center;">
                    <ul class="row">
                        <li class="col" style=" display:inline;padding: 10px 15px;">
                            <a class="tab-item" ng-click="myCam()">
                                <i class="icon  ion-camera"></i>
                                Camera
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col" style=" display:inline;padding: 10px 15px;">
                            <a class="tab-item" ng-click="myCam()">
                                <i class="icon  ion-camera"></i>
                                Gallery
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col" style=" display:inline;padding: 10px 15px;">
                            <a class="tab-item" ng-click="pdfUpload()">
                                <i class="icon ion-upload"></i>
                                Pdf
                            </a>
                        </li>


                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        </ion-content>

        <div class="bar bar-footer">
            <div class="tabs tabs-icon-bottom tabs-striped tabs-color-gray hide-on-keyboard-open" style="background-color: #11c1f3;">
                <a class="tab-item" ui-sref="app.homeApp">
                    <i class="icon ion-home"></i>
                    Home
                </a>

                <a class="tab-item" ng-click="myCam()">
                    <i class="icon  ion-camera"></i>
                    Camera
                </a>

                <a class="tab-item" ng-click="showDetails = !showDetails">
                    <i class="icon  ion-paperclip"></i>
                    Attach
                </a>

            </div>
        </div>

    </ion-view>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Hema Sorry For late reply Yes I found your Fiddle.

Comment: Please dont be sry.. I need to fix tht issue..  if i remove css class then this will work. But i want tht css classes

Comment: Please change <ion-view hide-back-button="true" > to <ion-view hide-back-button="true" ng-app="sampleApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl" > and then in JavaScript section click on drop down menu 'JavaScript (No-Library (pure JS))' and change 'Load type' to No wrap - in <head> instead of onLoad. This will fix your fiddle.

Comment: In my project those are all correct as you say. But here issue with css `.bar bar-footer`.If i remove tht `<div>` will be visible

Comment: Oh!! This is related to css issue then. If you remove this .bar bar-footer class then the position of your menu is disturbed because you have used scroll="false" and also used inline Padding in <div class="row" ng-show="showDetails"> this is not displaying the details menus. Please try scroll="true" and remove all static styling in "showDetail" <div>, you  may get your answer. If still this don't solve your issue then please let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163782/discussion-between-j-mean-and-hema).